# cant determing value of req.body.name - express node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm doing a like/dislike system. Here's the html code:

```
<form method="post" name="ratings">
    <input type="submit" name="vote" value="like">
    <input type="submit" name="vote" value="dislike">
</form>
```

In my index file, if I do

```
var inputValue = req.body.vote;
console.log(inputValue);
```

I get either "like" or "dislike" depending on the button I click. However, I can't seem to use this value. Like if I try using an if statement with this value, I get true regardless of what I compare it to. For example:

```
if (inputValue = "random") {
    console.log("random");
}
```

random is returned in console, even though req.body.vote == "like" or "dislike".

Comment: You compare with `==` or `===`, so it should be `if (inputValue == "random") {...`, making this a simple typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A single `=` assigns, `==` or `===` checks for equality

Change: `if (inputValue = "random") {`

To: `if (inputValue == "random") {`

See [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/does-it-matter-which-equals-operator-vs-i-use-in-javascript-comparisons) for information on which operator you should use for which usecase.

Comment: wow....im an idiot. dont know how i missed on this. thank you

Comment: To add to your answer: Never use ==. Because it passes truthiness tests whereas === is a deep equals. Use ===.

Comment: @PatrickMotard - *"never"* is a bit harsh, sometimes you want strict comparison, other times you don't.

Comment: @adeneo It is harsh, but I believe it is warranted. The danger of == is that it is logically equivalent to && *even when you don't intend it to be*. This unnecessarily puts you at risk for unintended behaviors. If you want to compare truthiness, use &&, else ===.